# Set component property in whole project (Radzen Blazor)

Tags: c#, web, blazor, radzen

I'm new with Radzen Blazor and my question is how to set properties to the components globally without doing it everytime in my code? for example I want to set the property "AllowFiltering" to "true" to all my "RadzenDataGrid" controls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own component as a wrapper where you set these defaults, and use your component going forward.

This way you can standardize your Data Tables throughout your application and also build in standard logic.